# Keep static class members in python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to keep a "static" defined multiprocessing Queue through multiple Processes, but it appears that this context is not copied to the new spawned process. Is there a way to keep them without storing them to derived process classes (so without self.q = A.q)?

main.py

```
from class_b import B

if __name__ == "__main__":
    b = B()
    b.start()

    while True:
        pass
```

class_a.py

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

class A(Process):
    q = Queue()

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__(daemon=True)
```

class_b.py

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from class_a import A

class B(Process):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(daemon=True)
        print(A.q)

    def run(self):
        print(A.q)
```

console

```
<multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x000001F77851B280>
<multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x0000023C420C2580>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include the code for class `A`.

Comment: Added code for class A

Answer (score 0):

When you import from `class_a.py` to access `A.q`, then so does `multiprocessing` in its own process. Then there will be two copies. You should create it as a local in `"main"` and pass it into `B`.

```py
from class_b import B
from multiprocessing import Queue

if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = Queue()
    b = B(q)
    b.start()

    while True:
        pass
```

Then make `B` store that reference for itself:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process

class B(Process):

    def __init__(self, q):
        super().__init__(daemon=True)
        print(q)
        self.q = q

    def run(self):
        print(self.q)
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep them without storing them to derived process classes (so without self.q = A.q)? - Thats basically what you did there (With a global reference, but still same principle)

Comment: I assume that you want there to be exactly one `Queue` and that all instances can see it. Well I think you are stuck with passing it around, otherwise each process will see their own: `class A(Process): ; q = Queue()`

Comment: I wonder if there are other means to copy the current context over, since for now I have done it kinda like you suggested, but with more Processes communicating with each other this gets really ugly really soon :/

Comment: It sounds like you need a `Context` class which is created with `the one` Queue and has member functions which create more processes and passes itself into them so they all have a reference to the one context right from the start.